# router link in v-if is working but url does not change

Tags: vue.js

i have succeed create router link in v-if but the url is does not change, what is expected is url change so if user click "go back one page" it is goes to previews page

```
<template>
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row" v-if="productAllData">
        <div v-for="item in productAll" :key="item._id" class="col-md-2 col-xs-6">
            <div class="card card-margin-right card-buttom" @click="clickProductById(item._id)">
            <img v-bind:src="item.image[0].filename" />
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">{{item.name}}</h5>
                <p>
                  {{item.description}}<br>
                  <span class="font-weight-bold">{{item.fprice}} / {{item.unit}}<br></span>
                  stock : {{item.quantity}}<br>
                </p>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <product-by-id :id="id" :test="`/productall/${id}`" v-if="productByIdData">
      <router-link :to="`/productall/${id}`"></router-link>
    </product-by-id>
    </div>
</template>
```

in above code there is router link in v-if

```
<product-by-id :id="id" :test="`/productall/${id}`" v-if="productByIdData">
  <router-link :to="`/productall/${id}`"></router-link>
</product-by-id>
```

and that code is working, since if i console log there is "/productall/603aaaf5dead94fee94d2811"
but why my url is not change still "http://localhost:8080/productall" what i expected is "http://localhost:8080/productall/603aaaf5dead94fee94d2811"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set up an example routing implementation.  A couple of components with a router configuration.

/router/index.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

Vue.use(VueRouter);

import Home from '@/components/stackoverflow/router-params-example/Home'
import ProductAll from '@/components/stackoverflow/router-params-example/ProductAll'

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'home',
    component: Home
  },
  {
    path: '/productall/:id',
    name: 'productall',
    component: ProductAll,
    props: true
  }
]

export default new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes
})
```

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app" class="container">
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>
```

Home.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="parent">
    <h4>Home</h4>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <router-link class="btn btn-primary" :to="{ name: 'productall', params: { id: productId } }">Product All</router-link>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        productId: '603aaaf5dead94fee94d2811'
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

ProductAll.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="product-all">
    <h4>Product All</h4>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <router-link class="btn btn-secondary" :to="{ name: 'home' }">Back</router-link>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: {
      id: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```